# dynamically spanning a div over a grid array

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I want to build a dynamic website that displays a kind of link list. The information for my links I have stored in a json-file that looks like that:

```
{
"name" : "Example 1",
"color" : "#9c88ff",
"serversystems": [
  {
    "name" : "example 1",
    "info" : "example text",
    "logo" : "logo.png",
    "instances" : [
      {
        "name" : "subexample 1",
        "link" : "#",
        "info" : "example text"
      },
      {
        "name" : "subexample 2",
        "link" : "#",
        "info" : "example text"
      },
      {
        "name" : "subexample 3",
        "link" : "#",
        "info" : "example text"
      },
      {
        "name" : "subexample 4",
        "link" : "#",
        "info" : "example text"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "example 2",
    "info" : "example text",
    "instances" : [
      {
        "name" : "subexample 1",
        "link" : "#",
        "info" : "example text"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "example 3",
    "info" : "example text",
    "logo" : "logo.png",
    "instances" : [
      {
        "name" : "subexample 1",
        "link" : "#",
        "info" : "example text"
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

One servertype can consist of a couple of serversystems, which in turn can consist of a couple of serverinstances.

My JavaScript gets all the data from the json-file, creates html-elements and appends them to the wrapper div.

To position these blocks on the website, my wrapper div spans a css grid:

```
#wrapper {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;

  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

The idea is to have it look roughly like this:
[what one servertype "block" should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Rs1.jpg)

The thing I just can't seem to figure out: as the number of systems and instances varies, the size of these blocks on my website varies as well. How can I use JavaScript to get the height of the final html-block (after appending all it's contents) so that I can make it span a certain amount of columns and rows on the grid?

Comment: i guess you just need to chunk the data into bits that fit the grid and for me its not clear how you want your data to be displayed or what you tried

Comment: Thank you for your answer @johnSmith ! I just updated my post a little bit, so that it makes more sense? The linked picture shows what the outcome should look like. My Javascript to make the block of html span over a certain amount of rows is a very ugly pile of a million if statements like "if numOfInstances = x, then elem.setAttribute("class", "span5"). My JS gets the data from the json file and creates html accordingly. I need to figure out how high the created element "would" be, so that I can make it span a fitting amount of rows on the grid.

Comment: i would display "subexamples" in a scrollable box so every box can have a the same maximum height, generaly the height of the "subexamples" itself should automatically scale the grid so you wont have to set a height